# How can I find the publication history of Python PEPs?

Tags: python, pep

While most PEPs have a created date, some do not, see [PEP 249](https://github.com/python/peps/blob/master/pep-0249.txt) for example.  I'm curious about the history of the PEPs.  Is there some resource that tracks the proposal, acceptance, and publication dates of such PEPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (1999) by emailing Python's db-sig.  In this case, 1999 is two years before the first git commit on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Git [commits history](https://github.com/python/peps/commits/master/pep-0249.txt) from that PEP.